# Error: Cannot link contract without an address

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

I'm writing test for my smart contracts with `truffle test`. I got these strings of code:

```
Library.new()
  .then((lib) => {
    console.log(lib.address); //0xd6f066a5b07562b6c8fdb6a59b7ba42036d5516c
    console.log(Library.isDeployed()); //false
    Deployer.link(Library); // Error: Cannot link contract without an address.
    ...
```

As you can see instance of library has an address but contract `Library` didn't handle it and still has `false` value in `isDeployed()` field. This weird behavior causes error on the next step when I'm trying to link my library to another contract.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by myself. Solution described here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/758#issuecomment-361688972